# How to Simplify the following coding for an array by minimizing the number of statements

Tags: javascript

How Simplify the following coding for an array by minimizing the number of statements:

```
var weekdays = new Array();
weekdays[0]= "Sun";
weekdays[1]= "Mon";
weekdays[2]= "Tue";
weekdays[3]= "Wed";
weekdays[4]= "Thu";
weekdays[5]= "Fri";
weekdays[6]= "Sat";
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What are you trying to do exactly? If you want, you can initialize the array directly by doing `var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", Sat"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var weekdays = ["Sun","Mon",Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can define an array in one line
var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
//Then you can loop the array using forEach() function
weekdays.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```